# Why am I receiving this error code in RStudio

Tags: r

I am attempting to fill in the matrix (first and last columns, then all inbetween and second last columns)filling based on if statement that checks if associated slope.filter was 1 and if not cross checks if neighbouring slope.filters were one, if yes, then keeps the point (i.e sets the point-filter to one, else zero). I have 17 rows in the csv I am working from but only 16 rows of data.

The error message is:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , n, value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  replacement has 16 rows, data has 17

    sorted.filter.no.duplicates[,c("row", "m.category", "sum")] <- list(NULL)
    Point.Filter.matrix <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = obs, ncol = n))
    Point.Filter <- sorted.filter.no.duplicates
    Point.Filter[is.na(Point.Filter)] <- 0
    Point.Filter.matrix[,1] <- Point.Filter[,1]
```

Comment: Well, you create `Point.Filter.matrix` with `obs` number of rows. How many is `obs`, 16 or 17? `Point.filter` apparently has 16 rows, because `Point.Filter[, 1]` has length 16. `Point.Filter.matrix` has 17 rows (according to your error message). You need to make that work, either by deleting a row from `Point.filter.matrix`, or by adding a value to `Point.Filter[, 1]` when you assign it, e.g., `Point.Filter.matrix[,1] <- c(Point.Filter[,1], NA)`, or by some other method. What do you want the result to be?

Comment: obs is equal to 17

Comment: So you're telling R to put 16 values in 17 places, and that doesn't work. R doesn't know where you want them to go (and neither do I).